# Low current in a motor used in a line following robot

Tags: motor, current, robotics

I'm trying to make a line following robot for my students, the problem is that I have not done any calculations (I don't know how).

The motor can't move the robot unless I connect it directly to the 9 V power supply, but when i connect the other compenents(arduino) in parralel to the same 9v powersuply the motor doesn't get enough current when put on the floor so it just freeze's.

Where do you think should i start ?

The transistor I used is: NPN C1815
the motor is a brushed dc motor
[image: schematic line following robot]

[image]

Comment: 9V power supply as in PP3 battery?

Comment: yes a 6F22 general purpose 9v battery

Comment: Does the motor have any form of gearbox?

Comment: @Majenko i added a photo of the motor to the post

Comment: Make your life easer next time.  Use 2 continuous servo motors instead of 1 regular motor and 1 regular servo.  The continuous servos are as easy to interface (directly to an Arduino) as a servo.  Then drive & steer your robot like a tank (left and right throttles).

Comment: You should not use a 9v battery for a motor project - it lacks the power to deliver voltage under load.  Additional, were it actually to deliver 9v it would destroy a typical hobby servo, which is intended for 4.5v - maybe 6v.  You are also missing the base resistor on your drive transistor.

Comment: Noticed that there is no base resistor between transistor and Arduino output pin, you may have blown the transistor and/or output pin, if not try a 1K.

Comment: @ChrisStratton do you mean that because the battery is 9v thats why it lacks power ? more volts less power !! i don't understand what you meant.
for the transistor base i used a 1k resistor i forgot it just on the schematic, for the servo i'll use a voltage divider

Comment: i used a 1k resistance i forget just in the schematic

Comment: Most 9V batteries have 6 AAAA batteries inside. Those are relatively small batteries, and can therefor not supply a lot of current. They will also deplete very fast. A 9V battery has 1/5th the capacity of an AA. My suggestion would be to use 4 AA batteries. You have special holders for 4 AA batteries.

Comment: @Gerben 4x AA will give 6volts? That's already on the limit for the Arduino Uno input voltage. I've used a 9.6V 2300mAh rechargable pack (https://www.conrad.nl/nl/nimh-accupack-96-v-2300-mah-conrad-energy-stick-tamiya-stekker-206671.html) which is great since it can supply 1C (2300mA) for one hour. Or run 300mA the whole day (8 hour) and it's rechargable. And the voltage is 9.6V so it can power the motors directly and the Arduino through regulated input. So I think such a 9.6V 2300mAh pack is very well suited for use in school. Though you really shouldn't short it out!

Comment: @Paul. 9V > 6V! Though 6V is probably on the low side for the regulator to work properly. You could use rechargeable AAs, which would give around 4.8V. PS nowhere in the question it's said that the motor is actually a 9V motor!

Comment: No! A 9v pack with meaningful current capacity will **destroy** that servo unless the circuit is changed to place a moderately high power regulator in front of it.  Hobby servos as made to run on 4 NiCd or Alkaline cells, or in some cases 5 NiCd (even 5 brand new alkalines could be risking damage).  Also the sensor pullups should really go the Arduino's regulated voltage, not the raw batter voltage.

Comment: ok i solved this using gears, and two separate power sources (9v transistor radio battery)
i also used a 1.5 amp transistor for driving the motor
thanks everyone

Comment: You seem to have ignored most of what was said.  Do not use 9v "transistor" batteries for motors - not one of them, not two of them.  Do not power a hobby servo from 9v.

Comment: What is a 1.5 amp transistor?

Comment: @ChrisStratton i did use a voltage divider for the servo, and i used one 9v low current battery for the motor and a 9v for the arduino, thats what i have in hand, i also changed the transistor to another one with a max Ic current of 1.5 ampere! i didn't ignore anything of what was said i hope, (i'm in a remote area, if i buy the proposed battery it will take about a month to arrive, by then students will be at holydays..

Comment: Voltage dividers are not appropriate for power unless feedback controlled. Feedback controlled voltage dividers are called linear regulators.  You should not use lithium batteries for such a project, nor 9v, just get ordinary AA's.

Comment: ok @ChrisStratton thank you very much for the information about voltage divider, i've never heard of Feedback controlled voltage dividers, i'll do a search about it and i will buy AA's because i can find them easily. thanks again

Comment: I should have added that, when using the 9V battery, only the motor can be driven directly from it. The servo should have a regulated source (5V is okay). I'm not sure if the Arduino can provide enough current for the servo, but it will do I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to only a tiny amount of gearing (what is it - 2:1? 3:1? something like that) your motor is operating near the stall point unless it is able to pick up enough speed (at which point it would smash into the nearest wall and pulverise itself).

Consequently it is drawing far more current from the battery than you'd like.  And that is, without the Arduino connected, about all the puny little PP3 battery can provide.  Add the Arduino etc into the mix and you are over-stepping your current budget by enough to mean the motor cannot start turning (the 1A stall current).

So what to do? Well, two options:

- Use a bigger battery.
- Increase the gearing of the motor.
- (my personal recommendation) Do both.

Increasing the gearing of the motor will decrease maximum output speed, increase the torque, and most importantly, decrease the start-up current. The whole load on the motor will be reduced making it much easier to start.

By increasing the power of the battery (use a 2S or 3S Li-Ion depending on what your motor's voltage limits are) you have a much bigger current budget to play with.

Comment: ok, thank you sir, i will give your recommandations a try